# Xcode Documentation Set for C++ Standard Library

Tags: c++, xcode, documentation

I've recently began using C++ with XCode and I'm starting to miss the integrated documentation that is available for Objective-C. I know that there is a way to generate documentation sets using Doxygen, but a readily available bundle would certainly be preferable...

Is there an *easy* way to get XCode to search at least the standard C++ library documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Doxygen is probably the easiest.  The [docs](http://developer.apple.com/tools/creatingdocsetswithdoxygen.html) are quite straighforward and simple.  Did you give it a shot?

In looking at the other [docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeWorkspace/200-Documentation_Access/documentation_access.html) it looks like it should be there already.  I was surprised it wasn't.